# Python data structure

Tags: python, data-structures

I know very little about programming, so this is a case of not knowing where to look for the answer. I am looking to create a data structure like the following:

```
vertexTopology = {vertexIndex: {clusterIndexes: intersection point}}
```

however cluster indexes in reality is a set consisting of the indexes of the clusters. So what I really have now is:

```
vertexTopology = {5: [[(1, 2, 3), intx_1], 
                      [(2, 3, 4), intx_2]]
                  6: [[(1, 2, 3), intx_3]]
                  ...}
```

How can I create a unique index associated to each cluster set AND its vertex index? Something like:

```
vertexTopology = {5: {index associated with (1, 2, 3) AND vertex 5, intx_1}, 
                     {index associated with (2, 3, 4) AND vertex 5, intx_2},
                  6: {index associated with (1, 2, 3) AND vertex 6, intx_3}]
                  ...}
```

I'm not sure that what I am looking to do is best achieve with dictionaries, so any suggestion is much welcomed!

Bellow is an image of a four point intersection, just so you can picture a bit what I dealing with.

[image: Four point intersection]

Comment: Upvote for the nice picture

Comment: What properties does your index need to have?  IIUC, the tuple `((1,2,3), 5)` would itself be a viable index; it's simple, hashable, sortable, etc.  Or you do want an integer?

Comment: Well you might be correct about that. The problem is I don't really know where collisions can happen, so I was kinda for a fail-safe approach. @EveryEvery's solution seems easy to implement. I'll go with that and test it thoroughly.

Comment: @grasshopper if you don't need some number or string for index, you can use tuple for key directly. it's more easy :-)

Comment: @grasshopper: if you use the tuple itself, there won't be any dangerous collisions.  There may be *hash* collisions, but that's an implementation detail behind the scenes: you'll never get the wrong value associated with the key.  If you try to replace the key by your own hash, then you *could* have dangerous collisions of the sort that I gave, because you're throwing information away.  [Similarly for the `frozenset`, which is even better because then you don't have to worry about the order.]

Answer (score 6):

There's a thing in Python called a frozen set. That's a set you can use as an index in a dictionary.

```
vertexTopology = {
    5: {
        (frozenset({1, 2, 3}), 5): intx_1,
        (frozenset({2, 3, 4}), 5): intx_2
    },
    6: {
        (frozenset({1, 2, 3}), 5): intx_3
    },
    ...
}
```

Unlike sets, frozensets are unmutable. That's why they can be used as an index.

Comment: I had tried using set as the key of the dictionary, but it didn't work. Glad you told me of using frozenset as a key.

Answer (score 3):

use hash() for generate index for cluster set and vertex index.
tuple is hashable type.

```
vertexTopology = {5: {hash(((1, 2, 3),5)): intx_1, 
                      hash(((2, 3, 4),5)): intx_2},
                  6: {hash(((1, 2, 3),6)): intx_3},
                  ...}
```

or use tuple as key

```
vertexTopology = {5: {((1, 2, 3),5): intx_1, 
                      ((2, 3, 4),5): intx_2},
                  6: {((1, 2, 3),6): intx_3},
                  ...}
```

if you data use set, tuple() can make tuple from set easily

```
s = set([1, 2, 3])    # s is set
t = tuple(s)    # t is tuple
```

UPDATE:

if you want other hash method. str() is easy solution.

```
In [41]: import hashlib

In [42]: hashed = hashlib.sha512(str(((1, 2, 3), 4))).digest()

In [43]: hashed
Out[43]:
'mtE7\xf6N\xfc\xca\xc7\xb1\x0fA\x86|\xbe9j\xbb\xdf\xbaa\xd1\x05V\x84\xe8S\xfb\xe1\x16\xe05\x89,C\xa8\x94n\xae\x1e\n\xc0Y-)\xfa\xceG D\xe0C\xc9\xef\xb0\x8eCk\xe3`\xc2s\x97\xec'
```

Comment: oh wow thanks! :D I kinda thought of a hash, but was using hashlib.sha224 () and it only seems to take strings. Didn't know hash() existed, or that it took tuples.

Comment: This could lead to unexpected collisions.  For example, `hash(((0,34,89),6)) == hash(((9,79,76),9))` for me.

Comment: all hash algorithm can have collision. if you want, you can use more safe hash algorithm.

Comment: @DSM . Gotcha! Given what I am working on, I'm pretty sure this can happen.

Comment: @EveryEvery: I guess what I'm getting at is that there's no need to throw information away by using the hash here when there are risk-free options.

Comment: @DSM you are right. I thought that grasshopper need some index key like number or string. my missunderstanding.  using tuple for key is risk-free option.

Comment: @grasshopper if you don't need some number or string for index, you can use tuple for key directly.

Comment: @EveryEvery Yes I'm implementing it using tuples as keys like DSM suggested. Will test for collisions when done...